# why NDK GetCurrentTime incorrect?

Tags: android, android-ndk, gettimeofday

I use the following code

```
unsigned long long appUtils::GetCurrentTime() {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return tv.tv_sec * 1000 + tv.tv_usec / 1000;
}
```

This code runs on the OSX platform. After clang is compiled, the output is 1618460301601. This result is correct
I am under NDK ,r17c r21d

```
unsigned long long  xx = appUtils::GetCurrentTime();
LOGD("app current time: %u %llu %lld", xx, xx, xx);
// OUTPUT app current time: 3553827972 15263574918903831684 6951239348438933920
```

However, I use NDK to compile and run on the emulator or mobile phone, and I will get this value 3553827972
How do I get the current time

Comment: I have include header file <sys/time.h>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%u` is the wrong format specifier to use, since it corresponds to `unsigned int`, which on all relevant platforms is a 32-bit type. The value 1618460301601 requires at lest 64 bits, so you need to use `%llu` or `%lld`.

If you built your code for a 32-bit ABI (e.g. armeabi-v7a or x86) then using that incorrect `%u` specifier for the first argument will also mess up the printing of the other arguments, due to how `printf`-like function process their integer arguments.